# Why am I getting 'Unfortunately (my_APP) has stopped' after running project and when I connect or disconnect device?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Here I am stucked with very strange error. My App is working fine but when I connect or disconnect my device to run it,it shows the message"unfortunately stopped.."
 Please help me to get out of it.
Here is the manifest file.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.medical"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Registration_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Registered"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_registered"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Diseases"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_diseases"
        android:permission="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Homepage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_homepage" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.About_us"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about_us" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Medicines"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_medicines"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Econtact"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_econtact"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Sos"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sos"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Setting"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_setting"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Setdata"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_setdata" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.ViewDisease"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_disease" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Diet"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_diet"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Diet_today"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_diet_today" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Ecall"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ecall" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Form"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_password"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.test.check.MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.View_medicines"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_medicines" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.medical.Ringalarm"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ringalarm" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: "unfortunately stopped.." please add log with question and related part of code

Comment: Your post contains almost nothing relevant to your error.

Comment: There is nothing in the log. my question is i am getting that error after i connect the device or disconnect it after running the App. So have any idea about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: downvoters care to explain the reason of downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had very simple solution,accepted my silly mistake..
I got my APP working properly just by removing these lines from **Manifest.xml** file

```
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" >
        </action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"        >
        </action>
```